# Using Bluetooth for sending files to remote mobiles using near mobiles!

Tags: mobile, routes, bluetooth

I need your opinion about my graduation project idea,

Using Bluetooth for sending files to remote mobiles by routing on near mobiles with enabled blue tooth and use them as intermediate stations until the sent files reach their destination.
Do you think its feasible and is appropriate for a graduation project?

Answer (score 1):

bluetooth meshing? maybe ...
but it would be inefficient as hell and won't work very well most the time.
And it would need a lot of cooperatation by the users (many users would need to install your software and have it running for your project to work in non-test-scenarios)